# Creating a Page Object in webdriver.io has error .setValue is not a function / cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io, webautomation

I'm creating a webdriver.io automation with a page object file (login.po.js) and a test spec file (test.spec.js), but it seem to be not able to recognize the object when i call it on the test spec file (test.spec.js), it shows an error `LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function`.

Here are my code below:

**login.po.js**

```
    var LoginPage =  {

    username: { get: function () { return $('#email'); } },
    password: { get: function () { return $('#password'); } },
    form:     { get: function () { return $('#login'); } },
    flash:    { get: function () { return $('#flash'); } },

    submit: { value: function() {
        this.form.click();
    } }
};
module.exports = LoginPage;
```

**test.spec.js**

```
var LoginPage = require('../page/login.po');

const userObj = {
    user: 'username@email.com',
    password: 'password',
}
var assert = require('assert');


describe('login form', () => {

    it('should deny access with wrong creds', function () {
        LoginPage.username.setValue('username');
        LoginPage.password.setValue('password');
        LoginPage.submit();
        browser.pause(5000);
        expect(LoginPage.flash.getText()).to.contain('Your username is invalid!');
    });

    it('should allow access with correct creds', function () {
        LoginPage.username.setValue(userObj.user);
        LoginPage.password.setValue(userObj.password);
        LoginPage.submit();
        browser.pause(5000);
        expect(LoginPage.flash.getText()).to.contain('You logged into a secure area!');
    });
});
```

error that would appear upon running it are:

```
 1) login form should deny access with wrong creds
 LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
 TypeError: LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
     at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:31:28)
     at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
     at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70

 2) login form should allow access with correct creds
 LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
 TypeError: LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
     at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:45:28)
     at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
     at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70
```

assistance on this would be greatly appreaciated, and if you also found other problem on my code, please assist me on correcting it, many thanks

---

changing the last line of code in **login.po.js**

```
exports.LoginPage = LoginPage;
```

shows an error:

```
  1) login form should deny access with wrong creds
  Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:20:28)
      at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
      at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70

  2) login form should allow access with correct creds
  Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:28:28)
      at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
      at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70
```

---

Editing the first line of code in **test.spec.js**:

```
var LoginPage = require('../page/login.po').LoginPage
```

still shows an error:

```
  1) login form should deny access with wrong creds
  LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
  TypeError: LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:31:28)
      at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
      at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70

  2) login form should allow access with correct creds
  LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
  TypeError: LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:45:28)
      at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
      at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70
```

---

github repository for the full code on this is:  `github.com/seanray7/pageobject-webdriverio`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spec file

```
const LoginPage = require('../page/login.po').LoginPage;
const userObj = {
    user: 'username@email.com',
    password: 'password',
}
const assert = require('assert');
const expect = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised')).expect;


describe('login form', () => {

    it('should have the right title ', async ()=> {
        await browser.url('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login');
        // expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('The Internet');
        let title = await browser.getTitle();
        console.log(title);
       return assert.equal(title, 'The Internet');
    });
    it('should deny access with creds', ()=> {
       return LoginPage.LoginPageLibs.Login(userObj.user,userObj.password);   
    });
});
```

page file

```
const LoginPageLocator = {

    username: '#username',
    password: '#password',
    form: '//i[contains(text(),"Login")]',
    flash: '#flash'

};

const LoginPageLibs = {
    Login : async (username, password) => {
        let name_ele = await browser.$(LoginPageLocator.username);
       await name_ele.setValue(username);
        let password_ele = await browser.$(LoginPageLocator.password);
       await password_ele.setValue(password);
        let sumbit = await browser.$(LoginPageLocator.form)
       return sumbit.click();
    },
    getText:async(elem)=>{
        let element = await browser.$(elem);
        return element.getText();
    }
}

exports.LoginPage = {LoginPageLocator,LoginPageLibs};
```

Refer this screenshot it ran succesfully.

[image]

Github - https://github.com/Bharath-Kumar-S/Wdio_sample.git

Comment: Changing the export portion of the code still shows an error, it says "Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined". 
 `` 1) login form should deny access with wrong creds
 Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
     at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:31:28)
     at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
     at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70``

Comment: Can you update the question with what changes you have done on exporting and importing?

Comment: If possible add the page and spec file in a simple git repo, I will clone and check the issue.

Comment: done, already edited the question, and here is the repo: https://github.com/seanray7/pageobject-webdriverio

Comment: I have edited the answer. Import Loginpage which you have exported from pages

Comment: still an error occurs:
 1) login form should deny access with wrong creds
 LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
 TypeError: LoginPage.username.setValue is not a function
     at Context.<anonymous> (D:\MyTest00\specs\test.spec.js:20:28)
     at Context.executeSync (D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:56:18)
     at D:\MyTest00\node_modules\@wdio\sync\build\index.js:82:70

Comment: Yes you have to change your approach of using webdriver calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209285/discussion-between-seanray-and-bharath-kumar-s).

Comment: SeanRay in the git repo package.json is missing. Can you upload it. I can execute the tests and help you out.

Comment: i have now added the package.json on the git repo, thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer. Clone my repo and check it out.